# Elasticsearch template not reading params

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mustache

I've been following the example at this site [Parameterizing Queries in Solr and Elasticsearch](https://dzone.com/articles/parameterizing-queries-solr) in the ES section. Note, it is an older ES version that the author is working with, but I don't think that should affect this situation. I am using version 1.6 of ES.

I have a template `{{ES_HOME}}/config/scripts/test.mustache` that looks like the below snippet. Note the `{{q}}` parameter in "query".

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "{{q}}",
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "fields": [
          "description^10",
          "name^50",
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "doctype" : {
      "terms" : { 
        "field" : "doctype.untouched"      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I POST to `http://localhost:9200/forward/_search/template` with the following message body

```
{
  "template": {
    "file": "test",
    "params": {
      "q": "a"
    }
  }
}
```

It runs the template, but gets 0 hits, and returns the following:

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "doctype": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        },
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if I hard code "a" into where {{q}} is, and post to the template, it correctly returns results for the query "a". Am I doing something inherently wrong in my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-template.html#pre-registered-templates), the `params` object should be outside of the `template` object

```
{
    "template": {
        "file": "test"
    },
    "params": {
        "q": "a"
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh. There are examples where they have file and params inside the template object, but that's only if the template object is inside the query object. This solved it